# Long and wide subtables

Tags: longtable, tabularx

I'm not a LaTeX expert. I'm using it to write my thesis. Here's my problem.

I have a set of tables and subtables, wich are very wide and long, so I'm using

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \begin{subtable}[]{\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|ll|X|}
                ..................................
                .... Very long and wide table ....
                ..................................
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Subtable 1 Caption}
        \label{tbl:subt1}
    \end{subtable}

    \begin{subtable}[]{\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|ll|l|}
            ..................................
            .... Very long and wide table ....
            ..................................
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Subtable 2 caption}
        \label{tbl:subt2}
    \end{subtable}
\caption{Global table caption}
\label{tbl:tbl}
\end{table}
```

I'm using tabularx to have the columns accomodate the text i have in the cells. What I get is only the first part of the first subtable, starting at a certain page an going down to the very end of the page (overflow).

How can I solve this? I've been bangin my head around with subfloat package and others but could not get it right!

Thanks everyone in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: hardly possible to answer given so little information but if the table is long get rid of the table, subtable and tabularx and just use `\begin{longtable}{llp{6cm}}` or some other suitable length than 6cm. it will then split over as many pages as needed.